# Making New Feature Class with Midpoint of Line Feature using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, geometry

I have a problem with creating a new shapefile ( for Points) with a midpoints from Line shapefile.

I cannot use FeatureVerticesTo Points_management because I only have access to Basic and Standard level licenses of ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1.

Is there another way to do this using ArcGIS Desktop tools or ArcPy functions?

Comment: You could write it in python, have a read of working with geometry objects.https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001z000000

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Add xy fields, right click on a header, pick calculate geometry, mid point X etc.

Comment: And you are restricted to ArcGIS? Did you consider other approaches, like QGIS?

Comment: Unfortunately, in that case I am limited to the Arcmap and arcpy environment. Maybe if it could work as independent python script in Qgis (I don't know too much Qgis environment with python). But I prefer stay with Arcmap.

Comment: Do you need the mid-points to be on an existing vertex, or the actual true mid-point of the line?

Answer (score 3):

Esri provides an [How To: Create a start, midpoint, and/or endpoint feature class of a line with an ArcGIS for Desktop Basic or Standard license](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012326) which describes:

> how to create a start, midpoint, and/or endpoint feature class from
> the vertices of an existing line feature class. This can be useful
> when working with an ArcGIS for Desktop Basic (ArcView) or Standard
> (ArcEditor) license and the Feature Vertices to Points tool is
> unavailable.

---

ArcGIS Pro (I tested version 3.1.1) provides an easy way to do this by using the [Generate Points Along Lines (Data Management)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/generate-points-along-lines.htm) tool which:

> Creates point features along lines or polygons at fixed intervals or
> by percentage of a feature's length.

Using a percentage of 50 and not including end points will create one point per line feature at its midpoint.

Comment: Absence of vertex is highly likely at mid point. Perhaps "..feature class from the vertices" is not completely correct.

Answer (score 1):

In arcpy, use the `positionAlongLine()` function with a distance of `50` and `use_percentage=True`.  See the documentation at:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/polyline.htm

You would need to use an `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()` for the line feature class, then for each line feature's geometry, run:

`pointGeom = lineGeom.positionAlongLine(50, True)`

Then convert the point geometry to a point feature and use an arcpy.da.InsertCursor()` to add it to your point feature class.

NB:  The point you get returned will NOT be one of the vertices.  It will genuinely be the half-way point along the line in terms of distance between the start and end points.